# How to enable header next-turn view in skobbler navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, skmaps

in demo version, I noticed header with arrows, pointing to next turn, together with distance and the name of the next street where the user needs to turn.

here is the screenshot:
[image]

I cannot figure out from documentation nor demo app how to enable it.
Anny suggestions?

Comment: The Navigation UI contains some out-of-the-box controls illustrating how to transform navigation events into UI notifications - look into the SDKTools project for code samples

Comment: I can't seem to figure it out. Can you maybe point me to where exactly in the project I could find the code I need?

Comment: I was looking through NavigationUIViewController, but cannot find it

Comment: See the SKTNavigationManager class as it implements the SKNavigationDelegate interface - inside check the didChangeFirstVisualAdvice callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, SKNavigationDelegate and SKRoutingDelegate must be implemented.

Don't forget to set delegates:

```
[SKRoutingService sharedInstance].routingDelegate = self;
[SKRoutingService sharedInstance].navigationDelegate = self;
```

And VERY important piece of code:

```
SKAdvisorSettings* advisorSettings = [[SKAdvisorSettings alloc]init];
[SKRoutingService sharedInstance].advisorConfigurationSettings = advisorSettings;
[Constants shared].route.requestAdvices=YES;
```

Then, after the route is calculated, you'll be able to play with these methods:

```
-(void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didChangeNextStreetName:(NSString *)nextStreetName streetType:(SKStreetType)streetType countryCode:(NSString *)countryCode
{
// This method returns the Name of the next street
_txtNextStreetName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",nextStreetName];
}

// This method returns visual guidance to the next turn on the road
-(void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didChangeCurrentAdviceImage:(UIImage *)adviceImage withLastAdvice:(BOOL)isLastAdvice
{
[_imgVisualAdvice setImage:adviceImage];
}
```

// And the distance

```
-(void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didChangeSecondaryVisualAdviceDistance:(int)distance withFormattedDistance:(NSString *)formattedDistance
{

    _txtNextStreetDistance.text = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"%@",formattedDistance];

}
```